# Issue with Xml and dataset

Tags: c#, xml

This problem is most likely pretty simple, but I am making a dataset and trying to save it to a file using XMLTextWriter

Now when i save my dataset and then attempt to read it will read the table names but shows the rows as 0? So it seems my writer is not writing the rows of the table?

Anyone know how I can fix this?

```
public static DataSet liveData = new DataSet();

    public static DataTable players = new DataTable("Players");

public static void WriteSchemaWithXmlTextWriter()
    {
        // Set the file path and name. Modify this for your purposes. 
        string filename = "Schema.xml";

        // Create a FileStream object with the file path and name.
        System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(filename, System.IO.FileMode.Create);

        // Create a new XmlTextWriter object with the FileStream.
        System.Xml.XmlTextWriter writer = new System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(stream, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode);

        // Write the schema into the DataSet and close the reader.
        liveData.WriteXmlSchema(writer);
        writer.Close();
    }

    public static void ReadSchemaFromXmlTextReader()
    {
        // Set the file path and name. Modify this for your purposes. 
        string filename = "Schema.xml";

        // Create a FileStream object with the file path and name.
        System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(filename, System.IO.FileMode.Open);

        // Create a new XmlTextReader object with the FileStream.
        System.Xml.XmlTextReader xmlReader = new System.Xml.XmlTextReader(stream);

        // Read the schema into the DataSet and close the reader.
        liveData.ReadXmlSchema(xmlReader);
        Console.WriteLine("y: {0}", liveData.Tables["Players"].Rows.Count);
        xmlReader.Close();
    }
```

Thank you for your help in advance :)

Comment: Apologies i cut off some of my code :)

Comment: public static DataSet liveData = new DataSet();

        public static DataTable players = new DataTable("Players");

Comment: Marca, I think you want to use `ReadXml` and `WriteXml` :)

Comment: I just found that works so much easier :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing the schema, which is the layout/structure of the Xml, rather than the actual content.

You need to use `DataSet.WriteXml` ...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135426%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

... instead!

Comment: So simple when you use the right thing :) Is there now a way to encode this so it cannot be modified externally? Thank you all

Comment: Encode what? The xml file/data? If you want people to read it, then I'm afraid they will be able to modify it! You can encrypt a file, but people will need the password to access it, and then they can modify it.